# How to trace where Props are coming from in React JSX, in a large code-base?

Tags: store, reactjs

In each file there is a defined set of `Proptypes` that the components in that file will be using. For example:

```js
    const Drafts = React.createClass({
       propTypes: {
         drafts: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
       },

       mixins: [State, Navigation],

       render() { 
       ...
      }
    });
```

What do I grep for? "drafts"? That is ineffective. How else can I find out from which `store` is that variable coming from?

Comment: You can grep for where that component is being used and then derive any connections to a store from there.

Comment: How do I grep for where the component is being used? I think this particular component's name is `Drafts`. But if I grep for "Drafts" many things come up, I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: We use React Developer Tools (Chrome) for this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en. You can find the component on the page and see its props and its parents.